# REST API call using nodejs on localhost

Tags: r, node.js, rest, api

I have made a REST API using R language.

```
#* @get /mean
normalMean <- function(samples=10){
  data <- rnorm(samples)
  mean(data)
}
```

I started the R server and tested the API using the url- http://localhost:8000/mean and it is working.

However when I tried to invoke the API using nodejs it returns an error:

```
Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1124:19)
at TLSSocket.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
```

Here is the nodejs code:

```
var https = require('https');
var optionsget = {
host : 'localhost', // here only the domain name
// (no http/https !)
port : 8000,
path : '/mean', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
method : 'GET' // do GET
};

console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
// uncomment it for header details
//  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.info('GET result:\n');
    process.stdout.write(d);
    console.info('\n\nCall completed');
});

});
```

I am not understanding where I am going wrong. I intend to make a put request in a similar manner after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that socket does not send connection `end` event within the timeout period. If you are getting the request via `http.request` (not `http.get`). You have to call `request.end()` to finish sending the request.

```
https.get('http://localhost:8000/mean', (resp) => {
console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);

    let result = 0;

    // on succ
    resp.on('data', (d) => {
        result = d;
    });

    // on end
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(result);
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually a newbie in nodejs. I tried changing the request to http.get also. And, tried calling request.end() also. Still stuck with the same error. Can you help me with where the changes need to be made for calling request.end()

Comment: @UjjwalGupta are you using the Plumber package?

Comment: Thanks it worked. And yes I'm using plumber package in R to expose the mean function.